# Trouble in Tab Bar rotation with two views

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, screen, uitabbar

I've got two similar views, in everyone there's a bottom toolbar with a botton and a textfield inside. (in toolbar autoresizing, autolayout & co. doesn't work...) In every controller there's method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        CGRect frameRect = _totaleTF.frame;
        frameRect.size.width = 230;
        _totaleTF.frame = frameRect;

        CGRect roundRect = _calcolaButton.frame;
        roundRect.size.width = 86;
        _calcolaButton.frame = roundRect;

    } else {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
        {
            CGRect frameRect = _totaleTF.frame;
            frameRect.size.width = 561; 
            _totaleTF.frame = frameRect;

            CGRect roundRect = _calcolaButton.frame;
            roundRect.size.width = 168;
            _calcolaButton.frame = roundRect;

        } else if(screenBounds.size.height==480) {
            CGRect frameRect = _totaleTF.frame;
            frameRect.size.width = 442;
            _totaleTF.frame = frameRect;

            CGRect roundRect = _calcolaButton.frame;
            roundRect.size.width = 141;
            _calcolaButton.frame = roundRect;
        }
    }
}
```

to resize button and textfield depending to screen orientation and they works! (woo!!!!) But method works only for his view; so, if I rotate screen in view1, view2's toolbar will remain with previous sizing; how can I solve it? Thank you very much!